# Error: The specified module 'SitecoreDockerTools' with version '10.2.7' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory

Tags: docker

When trying to initialize docker we are facing SitecoreDockerTools module not found.
**The specified module 'SitecoreDockerTools' with version '10.2.7' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.**

[image]

does anyone have any solution to resolve this issue?

Comment: Try to open init.ps1 and use -allowclobber parameter in Install-Module

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, try this solution.

Open `init.ps1` and use `-allowclobber` parameter in `Install-Module`.

[image]

Refer to this document for installation issues.

https://www.bugdebugzone.com/2020/09/install-sitecore-xp-10-to-developer.html

Hope this helps.